In Azure, how can I set the `accurate` scalingStrategy for Container App Jobs?
I'm using a ServiceBus to broker messages that will require us to spawn a ContainerApp Job execution for each message. However, I'm having trouble finding the proper configuration regarding the scalingStrategy.
Everything else is working fine and I'm spinning jobs up and down with messages on the queue, but I need to change the scaling strategy due to how we're using the bus and dequeueing the messages.
Specifically, I see that there should be a scalingStrategy of accurate which the KEDA documentation says to use if (like us) your queue does not include locked messages:
"accurate If the scaler returns queueLength (number of items in the queue) that does not include the number of locked messages, this strategy is recommended. Azure Storage Queue is one example. You can use this strategy if you delete a message once your app consumes it."
Since we are running long executions so we are using Receive-and-Delete mode instead of Peek-Lock on our ServiceBus, so we fall into this category where we are deleting the message as soon as we consume it.
But I'm not seeing any option to set scalingStrategy within the documentation related to Azure ServiceBus scalers, nor in the Azure documentation.
Has anyone figured out how to set this?
I'm expecting that there is a configuration option somewhere that I'm missing that would allow me to change the scaling behavior. Unfortunately, I can't use the default dequeuing mode of Peek-Lock or I'd switch to that and I think the default scaling strategy would work fine.

Read-and-Delete would be effectively the same for queue length information as not showing locked messages.  It means that when you query queue length information, you're seeing only the messages that no reader is processing.   Based on that, it would seem accurate applies to your situation.

Agreed thanks for the confirmation of that. My question is about how to set accurate in the Azure + ServiceBus scaling configs.

Unfortunately, that I cannot help with.

As you mentioned, the platform is using the ‘default’ scaling strategy, which handles ‘locked’ messages. Currently, there is no option for the customers to select different scaling strategies.
A workaround to ensure your job processes messages reliably would be using the visibility timeout feature to lock the message. Adjust the timeout based on your job’s duration. For example, if your job usually takes 5 to 30 minutes, consider setting the visibility timeout to 1 hour. Once your code finishes processing the message, it can safely delete it.
You can use QueueClient.UpdateMessage method to change visibility timeout.
Note: The product team has confirmed that they are planning to expose scalingStrategy as an option to customers, but there is no ETA yet.
